# Why won't my program find the main class correctly?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I'm making a program in java which is just a basic J based gui program. when i compile it in eclipse using the play button, it runs perfectly and there are no bugs or errors to be seen.

But when i export it and run it, it just returns an error saying the main class cannot be found, there shouldn't be a problem because i have the launch configurations set up correctly and for some reason this only happens when im programming in java 1.7, when i do it in 1.6 it compiles and runs perfectly. even when i export it.

How I export

[image: This is how i export it]

I just run it by opening to jar file

Inside my MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: net.undeadminecraft.wgh.main.Main
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

The error message i get

[image: the error message]

My packages (if it helps)

[image: packages]

Comment: There's some sort of reference, perhaps to another Jar file, that's present in Eclipse, but missing in your export.

Comment: Advise: use Maven or Ant for building projects

Comment: Could you post the exact error message you get when trying to run the JAR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your JAR on the console (`java -jar yourjar.jar`) and post the full stack trace. Also post output of `java -version` and `javac -J-version`.

My guess is that your default Java is Java6, and if you build with Java7, you are using the new Java7 class file format, or your main class contains a reference to a class not present in Java6 (in a place where verification cannot be deferred).

**EDIT:** Use [Process Explorer](http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe) or another task manager that shows exe paths and that can find process for a window, and show which `javaw.exe` exactly shows you that error message. Then try the `java.exe` in same directory to reproduce the error message. Or uninstall all your JRE (JDK may stay) but one, so it is clear which one is running.

Comment: When i run it from the console it works perfectly and returns no error o.O

Comment: I'm kind of confused, i reckon it would be fine if i just left it to run from a batch file. thanks for your help though :)

Comment: Hahaha, it turns out all i needed to do was update my Java... embarrassing!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to set your main class as the "Main-Class" in the MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: net.undeadminecraft.wgh.main.Main
```

Could solve your problem, as the main class you had in there is an internal class by Eclipse.

Comment: A blank line must be inserted in the last line. This is often the most critical point that needs attention

Answer (score 0):

Your main method signature is not correct. Please verify that it's like below :

```
public static void main(String args[]){ 
}
```

You may be missing something. Otherwise please give us your method declaration.

Comment: public static void main(String args[]){
  new Main();
 }

That's in the Main class